# How determine which object/image was clicked using javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html

Essentially, I have a page with 100 image thumbnails being displayed in the form:

```
   document.getElementById('response').innerHTML += "<a href='#'><img src=" + responseObject.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.high.url + " /></a>";
   document.getElementById('response').innerHTML += "<a href='#'><img src=" + responseObject.items[1].snippet.thumbnails.high.url + " /></a>";
   document.getElementById('response').innerHTML += "<a href='#'><img src=" + responseObject.items[2].snippet.thumbnails.high.url + " /></a>";
```

and so on. If it matters, I'm just dealing with an array of objects that are made of parsed JSON. Anyway, when the user clicks on one of the images, I need call a function, say showVideo, and I need to know which image item (items[1], items[2]) was actually clicked so I can pass it to my function and display the embedded youtube player for that item. In really rough terms, my function might look like:

```
function showVideo(itemClicked){
   document.getElementById('theVideo').innerHTML = "<iframe width='420' height='345' src=http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + responseObject.items[itemClicked].id.videoId + " /></iframe>"
}
```

I've been reading for a couple hours, but I can't seem to stumble upon a clean way to do this. Any ideas? I'd like to stick to javascript for this just to keep things simple for me for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use a [for() loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) to create each of your `<a>`:

```js
var responseObject={};
    responseObject.items=[
   {snippet:{thumbnails:{high:{url:'http://lorempixel.com/50/5'}}}, id:{videoId:`A1213131`}},
   {snippet:{thumbnails:{high:{url:'http://lorempixel.com/50/5'}}}, id:{videoId:`B1213131`}},
   {snippet:{thumbnails:{high:{url:'http://lorempixel.com/50/5'}}}, id:{videoId:`C1213131`}}
   ];

for (var i = 0; i < responseObject.items.length; i++) {
  //create the anchor
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  //set its href property
  a.href = '#';
  //insert the thumbnail into it
  a.innerHTML = "<img src=" + responseObject.items[i].snippet.thumbnails.high.url + i + " />";
  //add the click event
  a.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    //prevent it to act as an anchor;
    e.preventDefault();
    //insert the iframe into #theVideo
       //note that if the iframe is already setted up, it may be better to only change its src property document.querySelector(theVideo>iframe).src=...
    document.getElementById('theVideo').innerHTML = "<iframe width='420' height='345' src=http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + responseObject.items[this].id.videoId + " /></iframe>" +
      //only for the snippet example
      "<p>http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + responseObject.items[this].id.videoId + "</p>";
  }.bind(i)); //.bind(i) will make our `i` var correspond to the `this` var of the fired event.
  // append the newly created <a> to #response div
  document.getElementById('response').appendChild(a);
}
```

```html
<div id="response"></div>
<div id="theVideo"></div>
```

Comment: I like this! Seems like a more scalable solution, especially since my responseObject array is being pulled in from the JSON I get back from the YouTube API. It also taught me a different way to approach the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
<a class="video-target">...</a>
var elms = document.getElementByClassName('video-target');
elms.foreach(function (el) {
    el.onclick = function (e) {
        // e.target is the one you clicked on
        var target = e.target;
    }
}
```

You have to add a class to the HTML. Query the DOM, and find your element through `target`.

Comment: That looks good. What is e.target? An integer? A string? And, if it's a integer, can I count on it to be in order? In other words, if the user clicks on the 10th image on my page, can count on e.target to be 9?

Comment: e.target is the DOM element. Its an object.

Comment: I would get more familiar with the DOM. To get count info, you'll need to add that to the DOM element. Start by learning how to read DOM attributes.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it might be to use a onclick with each link tag with the item id 
    
So it becomes something like this
    `document.getElementById('response').innerHTML += "<a href='#'

    onclick="showVideo('0')"><img src=" + 
    responseObject.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.high.url + " /></a>";`